# Where is the script executed when logging into a shell?

Tags: login, command-line

When you login to either a tty or a remote machine by ssh there's normally a banner which looks like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-25-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

where is the script/group of scripts that produce this message located? I'd like to customise it.

I assume that it's part of the login process and not bash since you don't see it every time a terminal is opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at manpage `update-motd(5)` and the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`.  The text was originally called "Message Of The Day" and stored in `/etc/motd` (now a symlink to `/run/motd`).  That file is still there and updated as needed by background processes (likely `anacron` and `update-notifier`).

This can be suppressed by the presence of a `~/.hushlogin` file on a per-user basis.